# Updated: Solenoid on Momentary Button Circuit - Compatible components? Order to connect?

Tags: circuit-design, solenoid, button

Disclaimer: I have basically no experience or knowledge in electronic circuitry. I know a lot of people use an Arduino for this stuff, but this is just a one-off project for me.

I am making a jetpack thruster prop and need to circuit: the button to control, the solenoid that will push the air duster can, and the LEDs that will light up at the same time. Basically when I push the button I need the solenoid to extend and the LEDs to come on, and when I release the button I need the solenoid to retract and the LEDs to be off.

**UPDATE: Foregoing the LEDs and upgrading the solenoid.**

**Components Combatible?

- [Solenoid](https://www.adafruit.com/product/413)
- [Battery](https://www.homedepot.com/p/MIGHTY-MAX-BATTERY-12-Volt-7-Ah-Sealed-Lead-Acid-SLA-Rechargeable-Battery-ML7-12/307979135) (standard 12v 7Ah rechargeable)
- [Button](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1445) (not sure if this would work)
- [Heatsink for Mofset????](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3082)
- [Diode](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1641)
- [Resistor](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4294)
- [MOFSET](https://www.adafruit.com/product/355)
- [Wire](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Southwire-20-ft-14-AWG-Stranded-Red-GPT-Primary-Wire/3234601) (Positive)
- [Wire](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Southwire-20-ft-14-AWG-Stranded-Black-GPT-Primary-Wire/3197175) (Negative)

Wiring/Circuitry:
[image: My attempt, probably horribly wrong]
Blank: [image]**

From original post:
I need help with two things:

1. Are these correct and compatible components for this circuit:

- [Solenoid](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2776)
- [2 Pin Cable Adapter for Solenoid](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3814)
- [Battery](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4288)
- [Button](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1445)
- [Red LEDs](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2524) (I plan to use 3-5)
- [Transistor](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/irlb8721pbf.pdf)
- [Heatsinks for LEDs and Transistors](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3082)
- [Diode](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1641)
- [Resistor](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4294)
- [Wire](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Southwire-20-ft-14-AWG-Stranded-Red-GPT-Primary-Wire/3234601) (Positive)
- [Wire](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Southwire-20-ft-14-AWG-Stranded-Black-GPT-Primary-Wire/3197175) (Negative)
- And some sort of USB adapter between the Battery and wires???

2. Assuming those are the correct components, in what order/circuit do they need to be in? This is what I have, but I feel like it is totally wrong.
   [image]
   Also here is a blank image.
   [image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Oh those resistors a whole inadequate for those leds. How  bright you trying to get? And are you sure that solenoid can trigger what you want?

Comment: Looking to get decently bright for the LEDs, somewhere in their 150-300 lumen range. 

And the solenoid will be pushing the nozzle of aerosol can of air duster.

Comment: without design specs for solenoid force vs current vs battery capacity and a better LED design, this project is going to have a lot of problems and won't budge !

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer as this won't fit in the comments.

There are multiple issues with your chosen design.

1. Wiring: Your wiring diagram does not even seem to be accurate for what you want. The Transistor is probably not the best option here, a 5V Mosfet would be better. But it could work (but see 3.)
2. You will need resistors for the leds. BEEFY resistors. Since you want 9 Watts EACH, an led driver would be better, but some power resistors will work (at the major cost of battery life). But those are RGB leds. You seem to only want Red. By itself you could power just the red diode, but you be limited to 3W or 1W? **Honestly, the data sheet for that led is garbage so I can't even say what you can really put through it.** It says 2.5V for the red diode at 350 mA forward current, but the graph below it in the data sheet says 200 mA at 2.5V for the red. TLDR the resistors would need to be <10 Ohms at 2 or more Watts. Not those wimpy little 1k Ω 0.25 Watt ones.
3. The TIP120 will drop a lot at the currents you want. Assuming the low 2.25 Amp for the leds and 1 Amp for the solenoid, you are looking at a few VOLTS dropped (4V) with the TIP120. You'd be much better off with some IRF9540 mosfets (and that's just a random part).
4. The heat from the leds at 9 watts plus resistors at a few watts and the TIP120 at a few watts, you will need some active cooling if you run these for any amount of time.
5. Your powerbank can supposedly support 4.2 Amps at once, with 2.1 Amp per port. This may be good enough. But as Adafruit even says, it may shut down if less than 100 mA, and you may have to unplug and replug to get it to work, or jerryrig a keep-awake circuit like they link to. Just a FYI.
6. Are you sure your solenoid can actually pull the compressed air can open? Not to dash your hopes, but testing is needed for that.
7. Your Switch will have a much lower DC amperage compared to it's AC rating. It's no where near suitable to power your circuit in series. If you use it to trigger a few transistors or preferably mosfets, then it be fine.